# Вывести ограниченное количество option в select

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день, есть выпадающий список.

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
</select>
```

Необходимо что бы при нажатии отображались только первые 4, а остальные можно было выбрать с помощью скролла. Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливает высоту списка. Если значение атрибута size равно 1, то список превращается в раскрывающийся. При добавлении атрибута multiple к элементу  при size="1" список отображается как «крутилка». Во всех остальных случаях получается список с одним или множественным выбором.
Синтаксис:

```
<select size="<число>">...</select>
```

Comment: @SergeyVashchenko не за что, всегда старайтесь обойтись без JS если это реализуемо без него. Рано или поздно HTML поглотит его...

Answer (score 0):

Просто так это сделать не получится, но можно комбинировать атрибут `size` + JS.

```js
$(function() {
  var selectValue,
      $cSelect = $('.custom-select__select');
  
  getVal();
  $('.custom-select__selected-text').text(selectValue);
  
  $cSelect.on('change', function() {
    getVal()
    $('.custom-select__selected-text').text(selectValue);
    
    $(this).blur();
  });
  
  function getVal() {
    selectValue = $('.custom-select').find('option:selected').text()
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-select__select {
  height: 0; width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 100%;
}

.custom-select__selected-text {
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 18px 1px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 1px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.custom-select__selected-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px 3px 0 3px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 6px;
  margin: auto;
}

.custom-select__selected-text:focus + select,
.custom-select__select:focus {
  height: auto; width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-select">
  <div class="custom-select__selected-text" tabindex="1"></div>
  <select class="custom-select__select" size="6">
    <option value="1" selected>One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
    <option value="11">Eleven</option>
    <option value="12">Twelve</option>
  </select>
</div>
```